# WPF data binding: load x number of "instances" in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to load in xaml x number of instances of an object with properties. 
These instances are contained in a list (I currently have four) in a viewmodel.
I would like to "generate" as much xaml as needed to display these instances using (some kind of) databinding.

Note that I'm using the Caliburn.Micro framework.

*Example of 2 hardcoded "instances"*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxTHx.jpg

*My xaml*

```
 <StackPanel >
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <!--ticket vette titel-->
          <TextBlock Text="Ticket 1" Padding="5 5 5 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
                     FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

          <!--linkerkolom 1-->
          <StackPanel Margin="0 0 5 0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
            <TextBlock Text="TicketNumber: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Gebruiker: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Datum: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Status: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Vraag/Probleem: "/>
          </StackPanel>

          <!--rechterkolom 1-->
          <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="1 "/>
            <TextBlock Text="09/09/ "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Closed "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Ik kan mij niet aanmelden op de webmail "/>
          </StackPanel>
```

*the ViewModel that goes with it*

```
  class AlleTicketsViewModel : Screen
  {
    private static readonly ITicketManager mgr = new TicketManager();
    private List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>();
    public AlleTicketsViewModel()
    {
      tickets = mgr.GetTickets().ToList();
    }
```

Is there a way to databind an instance(take a property) to a xaml element (and when the first instance is bounded, to select the next one)?

And can xaml be "generated" in such a way?

Comment: you can make your custom user control with associated properties and then instantiate and add one of its instances to a parent container. Or as an easier approach, you may change the item template of a listview and bind your collection to your listview. I would prefer the second approach.

Comment: something like the the last few samples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Comment: Use an ItemsControl.

Comment: I did some googling and an itemscontrol needs to be initialized in the code behind file.  icTodoList.ItemsSource = items; Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ItemsControl` and bind its `ItemsSource` property to the collection property of the view model:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--ticket vette titel-->
                <TextBlock Text="Ticket 1" Padding="5 5 5 5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
                     FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                <!--linkerkolom 1-->
                <StackPanel Margin="0 0 5 0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <TextBlock Text="TicketNumber: "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Gebruiker: "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Datum: "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Status: "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Vraag/Probleem: "/>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--rechterkolom 1-->
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TicketNumber}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gebruiker} "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status} "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Problem}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Since you can only bind to *public properties*, you need to expose the `List<Ticket>` as well as all properties of the `Ticket` class, as such:

```
class AlleTicketsViewModel : Screen
{
    private static readonly ITicketManager mgr = new TicketManager();
    public List<Ticket> Tickets { get; } new List<Ticket>();
    public AlleTicketsViewModel()
    {
        Tickets = mgr.GetTickets().ToList();
    }
}
```